# Analytical solution of second order non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two coupled non linear ODE

$$
\begin {align}
y_1''&=(y_1-y_2)+((y_1-y_2)^3)/6, \\
y_2''&=1+((y_1-y_2)^2)/2
\end{align}
$$
How can I solve these equations analytically to get the value of $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: You chnaged the system adding $(y_1-y_2)^3$ instead of a square

Comment: yes Sir. In actual equation v^3 term is there. I typed v^2 by mistake.

Comment: when I am solving the equation, I am getting the solution in terms of v that is I am getting relation between y_1 and y_2. How can I get the values of y_1 and y_2 ?

Comment: so how can I proceed to solve it analytically? Kindly help

Comment: Non-linear ODEs almost *never* have analytical solutions. And we have far less methods for solving such equations than what we do in the linear case. Is there any reason you expect this system to have an analytical solution? Where does it come from, what is the context you encountered this one? In this case one *might* be able to analytically solve for $z = y_1-y_2$, but even that looks horrible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a particular solution which satisfies $y_1-y_2=c$ (constant).  Taking $d^2/dt^2$ of this condition and using the ODES gives
$$
c+c^3/6=y_1''=y_2''=1+c^2/2.
$$
This equation for $c$ is cubic, so there exists a real solution.  Returning to $y_2''=1+c^2/2$, we conclude that $y_2=\frac{1}{2}(1+c^2/2)t^2+at+b$, and hence $y_1=y_2+c=\frac{1}{2}(1+c^2/2)t^2+at+b+c$.  Here, $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants, while $c$ is a solution of the cubic above.